# How to insert blank line using reStructuredText / Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to add a blankline (or add more whitespace) between heading and the image using ReStructuredText:

```
====
John 
====

.. image:: _static/john.JPG
   :alt: John
   :height: 300px
   :width: 400px
```

But I don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the pipe vertical line key as shown below

```
   ====
   John 
   ====

   |

       .. image:: _static/john.JPG
           :alt: John
           :height: 300px
           :width: 400px
```

That should work.

Comment: This interts white space only.

Comment: not working if no text written after pipe